# android:Image burning effect/Animation

Tags: android, image, canvas, android-animation, paint

I am developing an application in which i want to show image burning effect as-

1)Image starts burning at top right corner

2)It will continue to burn until bottom left corner reach.

3)As burning processes its burning part should be invisible.

4)when it will reach to bottom left corner,whole image should disappear.

following Image may help you to get my idea,
[image]

Comment: i tried using two images 1)original image 2)default burn image;the idea was place the burn image at to right of original and move it downward,though it work at some extent but visibility of burned portion is the issue here,so i left this solution and trying to find another

Comment: Hello @dd619 If you have found any solution please help me. I also required the same solution. Thanks.

Comment: @HiteshSarsava I didn't find any solution for this, sorry.

Comment: then how did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

use drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint). With that you can specify which part of the source image will be visible, so through time you can specify the position and size of the image at each time that will be rendered.